# Using D-Link Wireless N150 ROUTER as an access point, can it be done?

Tags: router

I have this D-Link Wireless N150 Home router and would like to know if I can use it as an access point to extend my wireless signal. I´ve tried with no success. I cannot enter to the IP address 192.168.0.1, nor any other (I´ve tried several).

I´ve tried to access it and configure it the same way I did with an access point that I have, connecting it to a PC that´s wirelessly connected to the internet.

I´ve googled about it and didn´t find any information about that particular model.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this router as an access point by installing the DD-WRT firmware.  Here's a link to instructions for configuring the access point:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point

Here are instructions on installing the firmware:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=88838